# TextField @State property value = ""

Tags: swiftui

I'm studying SwiftUI and I'm having a hard time dealing with TextField.
When I do onCommit, I tried to put "" in the @State Property value, but there was no response.

What I'm trying to do is click the'retrun' key in TextField and I want to show you the gap where the text created disappeared.

```
struct TodoTextFieldView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel
    @State var textFieldText = ""
    var title: String = "here typing line"
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            HStack(spacing: 5){
                Text("")
                    .font(.title)
                TextField("\(title)",
                          text: $textFieldText,
                          
                          onCommit:{ addItem()
                    // 
                })
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .underline()
                    .font(.headline)
            }.padding(.leading, 40)
        }.padding(16)
        

    }
    func addItem() {
        
        listViewModel.addItem(title: textFieldText)
        textFieldText = "" // This is where I want to do it.
        
        print(textFieldText)
    }
```

This is a parent view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel
    
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            TodayView()
            Spacer()

            TodoTextFieldView()
            Spacer()

                /// List view
                List{
                    ForEach(listViewModel.items) { item in
                        ListView(item: item)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation(.linear){
                                    listViewModel.updateItem(item: item)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                     .onDelete(perform: listViewModel.deleteItem) // Delete
                     .onMove(perform: listViewModel.moveItem) // Edit
                }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                
                        
        }.navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton()) // Edit Button
        .padding()
    }
}
```

```
@State var textFieldText = ""
```

The value was directly added to the state property. But there is no reaction.

```
 textFieldText = ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emptying the binding property of `TextField` inside the `Task` block works for me.

```
func addItem() {        
    listViewModel.addItem(title: textFieldText)
    Task {
        textFieldText = "" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I've been googling for more than 5 days, but I didn't know, so I was in despair Thank you again.